# How can I report an issue on a BitBucket hosted Open Source project?

Tags: bitbucket

I am using an Open Source project that is hosted on BitBucket. There's a couple of small bugs I'd like to communicate to the author - but **I can't find an issues tab or anything similar anywhere in the UI**.

How can I report an issue on a BitBucket hosted Open Source project?